# "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat" for dist folder

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am using Angular 13 and the command "ng add ngx-bootstrap" installed the following:
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^8.0.0",

Now it fails to find the dist folder. Angular CLI adds **"./dist/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"** to the angular json. You can see form the below,  but actually there is no such a file. I changed this line to **"./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"** so it is working now. But do you know why this inconsistency happens? Am I doing something wrong?

```
  "styles": [
     "./dist/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
     "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
     "src/styles.css"
  ],
```

Comment: I am getting the same error now. As you said I changed to "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css" and is working now.

Answer (score 3):

[You have to change the path from ./dist to ./node_modules in angular.json file [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4waf.png)

Comment: thanks. but why ngx-bootstrap wrote `dist` there